# mintV2 with umi Error: Method not Implemented

Tags: metaplex, nft, mint, candy-machine-v3, candymachine

I'm trying to mint with umi's mintV2 method on devnet for a candy machine that does not have pNFTs set up. The Metaplex doc says

> the new mintV2 instructions can be used to mint regular NFTs

but I'm getting this error:

> Error: Method not implemented.

Here is my code:

```
const nftMint = generateSigner(umi);
const result = await transactionBuilder()
  .add(setComputeUnitLimit(umi, { units: 800_000 }))
  .add(
    mintV2(umi, {
      candyMachine: candyMachine.publicKey,
      nftMint,
      collectionMint: candyMachine.collectionMint,
      collectionUpdateAuthority: candyMachine.authority,
    }),
  )
  .sendAndConfirm(umi);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to install the correct tag for mpl-candy-machine. Needs to be @alpha.

```
npm install \
      @metaplex-foundation/umi \
      @metaplex-foundation/umi-bundle-defaults \
      @solana/web3.js \
      @metaplex-foundation/mpl-candy-machine@alpha
```